# Missing type specifier - int assumed error

Tags: c++

I have error "Missing type specifier - int assumed". I googled for this error but it I can't find solution for it. Weird thing is that when I delete the line where the error is and all calls for allLeagues in the constructor, so there is no error anymore, and then again when I write the same lines it's working alright until I make a change into my code.

Here is my GameManager class which is singleton:

.cpp:

```
#ifndef GameManager_H
#define GameManager_H

#include "PlayedMatch.h"
#include "League.h"


class GameManager
{
 public:

void Update(); // Called every frame

void AdvanceOneDay();

static GameManager &GetInstance();

Team allTeams[4]; //This var holds all the teams

League allLeagues[2][2]; //Error in this line. Also another error mising ; before identifier allLeagues



enum Leagues
{
    Spanish,
    English
};

enum SpanishLeagues
{
    LigaBBVA,
    SegundaDivision
};

enum EnglishLeagues
{
    PremierDivision,
    Championship
};

 private:

int gameDay, gameMonth, gameYear;

void operator=(GameManager const&);

//Default Constructor
GameManager();

//Destructor
~GameManager();

 };

#endif
```

.h default constructor:

```
GameManager::GameManager()
{
allLeagues[0][0] = League("LigaBBVA", 1, 1);
allLeagues[0][1] = League("Segunda Division", 1, 1);
allLeagues[1][0] = League("PremierDivision", 1, 1);
allLeagues[1][1] = League("Championship", 1, 1);

allTeams[0].SetName("Barcelona");
allTeams[0].SetAttack(100);
allTeams[0].SetDefense(90);
allTeams[0].SetLeagueX(Spanish);
allTeams[0].SetLeagueY(LigaBBVA);

allTeams[1].SetName("Real Madrid");
allTeams[1].SetAttack(90);
allTeams[1].SetDefense(90);
allTeams[1].SetLeagueX(Spanish);
allTeams[1].SetLeagueY(LigaBBVA);

allTeams[2].SetName("Manchester United");
allTeams[2].SetAttack(70);
allTeams[2].SetDefense(80);
allTeams[2].SetLeagueX(English);
allTeams[2].SetLeagueY(PremierDivision);

allTeams[3].SetName("Chelsea");
allTeams[3].SetAttack(60);
allTeams[3].SetDefense(70);
allTeams[3].SetLeagueX(English);
allTeams[3].SetLeagueY(PremierDivision);


gameDay = 1;
gameMonth = 1;
gameYear = 2013;

for (int team = 0; team < (sizeof(allTeams) / sizeof(allTeams[0])); team++)
{
    allLeagues[allTeams[team].GetLeagueX()][allTeams[team].GetLeagueY()].SetTeam(team, allTeams[team]);
}
   }
```

League class:
.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "Team.h"
#include "GameManager.h"

class League
{
public:

//Default Constructor
League();

//Overloaded Constructor
League(std::string name, int startingDay, int startingMonth);

//Destructor
~League();

void SetTeam(int, Team);

void CreateSchedule();

  private:

Team teamsInLeague[2];

std::string name;

int startingDay, startingMonth;
  };
```

.cpp:

```
#include "League.h"


League::League()
{
name = "";
startingDay = 1;
startingMonth = 1;
}


League::~League()
{

}

League::League(std::string name, int startingDay, int startingMonth)
{
this->name = name;
this->startingDay = startingDay;
this->startingMonth = startingMonth;
std::cout <<"Name: " << name << endl;
}

void League::SetTeam(int index, Team teamToAssing)
{
teamsInLeague[index] = teamToAssing;
}

void League::CreateSchedule()
{

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this not remotely suggest to you that something is wrong with the ability of the compiler on that *specific* line to know what a `League` is ? And can you see that `League.h` includes `GameManager.h`, which includes `League.h` ? Hmmm... From what I can see, there is no reason for `GameManager.h` to be included in `League.h`. Nothing is gained nor used from that header.

Comment: In your question, you seem to have the .cpp and .h files mixed up (I.e., the section labelled ".cpp" contains stuff that usually would be in the .h file, and vice versa. Is this mixed up just in your question, or is it mixed up in the actual code?

Comment: Errors aside, I'd advise against hard-coding anything league or team-related. Just have a file containing that info and parse it at run-time. You don't want to modify and re-compile the source code every time you add a new league and teams, right? (I'd know)

Answer (score 3):

League.h includes GameManager.h, and GameManger.h includes League.h. That's the reason for your error.

Looking at the code I see no reason that League.h should include GameManager.h, so remove that include and you should be fine.

Comment: Literally typing this nearly verbatim in comment when you posted it, so naturally... +1 =P